# Rendering RadioGroup elements

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm using HTML::FormHanlder here.
I'm trying to get different output with rendering radio buttons ([using this method](https://metacpan.org/module/GSHANK/HTML-FormHandler-0.40017/lib/HTML/FormHandler/Manual/Rendering.pod#Rendering-labels)). Field declaration goes like this:

```
has_field 'xxx' => ( type => 'Select', widget => 'RadioGroup', build_label_method => \&build_label );

  sub build_label {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->name;
}
```

The problem is, the only `<label>` is in elements grouping header:

`<label for="xxx">Lorem ipsum</label>`,

so it changes that.

Radio buttons stay unchanged like `<input type="radio" name="xxx" id="xxx" value="2"/>
I'm not changed`

So naturally I'm wondering how to change automatically rendered "I'm not changed" (in this case) text that goes after `<input/>`

Here's an example to make it more clear:

```
<label for="0.xxx">This is the only part that gets changed with sub build_label</label>
<label class="radio" for="0.xxx.0">
    <input type="radio" name="0.xxx" id="0.xxx.0" value="2"/>
    How to change rendering method of this part?
</label>
<label class="radio" for="0.xxx.1">
<input type="radio" name="0.xxx" id="0.xxx.1" value="1"/>
    And this one?
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would depend on why you want to change the label for the radio group option. If you look at the code in HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Field::RadioGroup, you can read how the field is rendered.

Normally you would construct the option list with the label that you want. You could provide an options_method on the field:

```
has_field 'xxx' => ( type => 'Select', widget => 'RadioGroup', options_method => \&build_xxx_options );
sub build_xxx_options {
    my $self = shift; # $self is the field
    <build and return options with desired labels>;
}
```

If you want to localize the label, that will happen automatically if you provide suitable translation files to maketext. Even if you don't want to localize the string, you could make use of the fact that the label is localized (my $label = $self->_localize($option_label);) and provide a localize method for the field, by setting 'localize_meth' to a method reference:

```
has_field 'xxx' => ( type => 'Select', widget => 'RadioGroup', localize_meth => \&fix_label );
sub fix_label {
    my ( $self, $label ) = @_; # $self is the field
    if ( $label eq '...' ) {
        return '....';
    }
    return $label;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to register and answer, you got me on right track. Somehow `options_method` didn't work as expected (I couldn't get `$self->schema` etc), but `sub options_<fieldname>` did the job.
P.S. I really did go looking for source code, tried to create a new Moose::Role which had `with 'HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Field::RadioGroup'`, so I could modify `wrap_radio` method but I figured that I couldn't use DBIx::Class there so I had to try smth else :)

Comment: The 'options_method' provides a field method, so the schema is in $self->form->schema. The 'options_<fieldname>' method is a form method, so the schema is in $self->schema. It would be possible to use a 'label_method' callback in the RadioGroup and CheckboxGroup widgets, but it's not clear to me whether that's needed since the options can be created with the correct labels.